# Directional Shadow is not creating in thee.js

Tags: three.js

I'm new learner of `Three.js` and following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJAfLdUgdc4&list=PLjcjAqAnHd1EIxV4FSZIiJZvsdrBc1Xho&index=1&t=1620s)

My issue is that I want to create shadow of sphere on plane geometry  but I have done same as tutorial but I failed to create shadow..

Please point out my mistake. Thanks

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

// Controls
const orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

//  Sets the x, y, and z axes with each having a length of 4
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
scene.add(axesHelper);

// camera.position.z(4);
camera.position.set(40, 40, 40);
orbit.update();

const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
scene.add(box);

// Plane Geometry
const planGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30, 30);
const planMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planGeometry, planMaterial);
scene.add(plane);
plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
plane.receiveShadow = true;

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(30);
scene.add(gridHelper);

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3);
const spherMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xff0,
  wireframe: false,
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, spherMaterial);
scene.add(sphere);
sphere.position.set(-10, 10, 0);
sphere.castShadow = true;

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(directionLight);
directionLight.position.set(-30, 50, 0);
directionLight.castShadow = true;

const dLightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(directionLight, 5);
scene.add(dLightHelper);

const gui = new dat.GUI();

const optionsPhere = {
  sphereColor: "#ffea00",
  wireframe: false,
  speed: 0.01,
};

gui.addColor(optionsPhere, "sphereColor").onChange(function (e) {
  sphere.material.color.set(e);
});
gui.add(optionsPhere, "wireframe").onChange(function (e) {
  sphere.material.wireframe = e;
});
gui.add(optionsPhere, "speed", 0, 1).onChange(function (e) {
  sphere.material.speed = e;
});

let step = 0;
function animate(time) {
  box.rotation.x = time / 1000;
  box.rotation.y = time / 1000;

  step += optionsPhere.speed;
  //   sphere.position.x = 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
  sphere.position.y = 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
  //   sphere.position.z = 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.9/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question to a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and note that tutorial has a [tutorial-code](https://github.com/WaelYasmina/threetutorial/blob/main/src/js/scripts.js), you can compare that code with your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a lit material for your ground since shadow is defined as the absence of light. `MeshBasicMaterial` does not react on lights.

Besides, makes sure to enlarge the shadow camera's frustum a bit. You can easily debug this with `THREE.CameraHelper`:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

// Controls
const orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

//  Sets the x, y, and z axes with each having a length of 4
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
scene.add(axesHelper);

// camera.position.z(4);
camera.position.set(40, 40, 40);
orbit.update();

const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
scene.add(box);

// Plane Geometry
const planGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30, 30);
const planMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planGeometry, planMaterial);
scene.add(plane);
plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
plane.receiveShadow = true;

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(30);
scene.add(gridHelper);

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3);
const spherMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xff0,
  wireframe: false,
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, spherMaterial);
scene.add(sphere);
sphere.position.set(-10, 10, 0);
sphere.castShadow = true;

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(directionLight);
directionLight.shadow.camera.right = 20;
directionLight.shadow.camera.left = - 20;
directionLight.shadow.camera.top    = 20;
directionLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 20;
directionLight.shadow.camera.far = 100;
directionLight.position.set(-30, 50, 0);
directionLight.castShadow = true;

scene.add(new THREE.CameraHelper(directionLight.shadow.camera));

const dLightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(directionLight, 5);
scene.add(dLightHelper);

const gui = new dat.GUI();

const optionsPhere = {
  sphereColor: "#ffea00",
  wireframe: false,
  speed: 0.01,
};

gui.addColor(optionsPhere, "sphereColor").onChange(function (e) {
  sphere.material.color.set(e);
});
gui.add(optionsPhere, "wireframe").onChange(function (e) {
  sphere.material.wireframe = e;
});
gui.add(optionsPhere, "speed", 0, 1).onChange(function (e) {
  sphere.material.speed = e;
});

let step = 0;
function animate(time) {
  box.rotation.x = time / 1000;
  box.rotation.y = time / 1000;

  step += optionsPhere.speed;
  //   sphere.position.x = 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
  sphere.position.y = 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
  //   sphere.position.z = 10 * Math.abs(Math.sin(step));
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.9/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```